# Получить аватар пользователя VK SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем доброго времени суток.
Стал вопрос по использованию библиотеки VK/
Как получить изображение профиля при авторизации используя VKSDK

Comment: @Oneills, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

После авторизации отправить запрос примерно такой запрос:
в photo_max_orig_url ссылка на изображение

```
 VKParameters params = new VKParameters();
    params.put(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_max_orig");

    VKRequest request = new VKRequest("users.get",params);
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            JSONArray resp = response.json.getJSONArray("response");
            JSONObject user = resp.getJSONObject(0);
            String photo_max_orig_url = user.getString("photo_max_orig");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            super.onError(error);
        }
});
```